# Ionic - Position error:application does not have sufficient geolocation permission

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, geolocation, ionic5

Using Ionic :

- Cordova CLI 11.0.0
- Cordova Platform 9.1.0
- Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.16 (C:\PP\Ionic2020\node_modules\ionic)
  Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 6.0.4
  @angular-devkit/build-angular : 13.0.4
  @angular-devkit/schematics    : 13.0.4
  @angular/cli                  : 13.0.4
  @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 5.0.3

  In a very simple app, in this example: https://www.positronx.io/ionic-cordova-geolocation-and-geocoder-tutorial-with-examples/

  when I use "ionic serve" app in browser is ok, but when I launch it on my device (ANDROID), using "ionic cordova run android", I obtain "Position error:application does not have sufficient geolocation permission" even if I allow geolocation in app preferences.

In older app, that use Cordova platform 8.1.0, geolocation is ok, so, I think it's a 9.1.0 platform problem.

But, how to solve it?

Comment: Hey try running ionic cordiva platform add android@10 and install android SDK build tools 30.0.3 version and run in android let me know if it resolved currently android 9.1.0 is not working

Comment: perfect, using android 10, solved my problem. Thanks